# Moderators following Rules and Setting Good Examples

Tags: discussion, support

When a general user posts something off topic a moderator can moderate it simply. In case moderators do it is not that easy as it requires many people to report it. Historically this has not happened in this site.

There should be a way to keep the moderators made to follow the rules?

Moderators blatantly breaking the rules and standards they try to impose on other is not a good example.

---

Some example content:

- https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/a/19307/295 (The content is not related to Buddhism through the OP fanatically tries to some remote connection)
- [The terror tragedy in France in Buddhist light](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/12610) (In this case also seems like an offtopic question)
- https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/a/18986/295 (Most ontent does not seem to relate to Buddhist theory or practice)

This discussion does not have to do anything with specific content thought this triggered the discussion.

Comment: I think this is a duplicate of [Off Topic Content](http://meta.buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/2046/254) and [How do you delete a moderator's answer?](http://meta.buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/1456/254) and maybe others. If you want to discuss the content of a single specific question or answer then please do that.

Comment: This is about moderators following the standards they are supposed to uphold.

Comment: I see this as two topics: 1) how are SE sites governed, what is the role of moderators etc. 2) are these specific answers on-topic, and if not why not and how to improve them. And I think that `1) how are SE sites governed` is already in other topics (so this a duplicate of those), and that `2) are these specific answers on-topic` (if you want to discuss that) is better discussed in separate meta-topics, each using the [meta-tag:specific-answer] tag, with the discussion being specifically about the content of the answers in question (and not about "moderators").

Comment: Can you point to the other specific topics?

Comment: [Off Topic Content](http://meta.buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/2046/254) is a general topic about how you can handle off-topic content.  [How do you delete a moderator's answer?](http://meta.buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/1456/254) (and others like [How do you Initiate Moderator Removal?](http://meta.buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/1457/254)) answer questions to do with how to handle rogue moderators. I don't think it's useful to discuss those kinds of issues again here, but there **is** room for discussion about specific answers [as you did here](http://meta.buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/2049/254).

Comment: This is not about removing or deleting but moderators adhering to the same standards.

Comment: Well the point of discussing specific answers is to discover (and agree or disagree on) what those "standards" are, and to discover why the answer in question does or doesn't meet those standards.

Comment: Following the "rules" is a controversial topic but If a moderator acts as an abuser, criminal etc. and If has personal characteristics that is completely opposite of the "real moderator" characteristics, the site administration has to immediately remove that moderator without waiting one second. Otherwise people has to explain things with "details" that would cause more damage to the moderator

Answer (score 1):

Please stop spamming the site with questions that are nearly duplicates.

Buddhism SE is not as strict as other SE's. We have compassion here:)

Answers/questions can be edited if needed, thats why we have an edit button.

I don't think any moderators here are either rogues or have any bad intentions. I do think that moderators and members here have a lot of compassion and only wants to help other beings. Thats the reason we post here.

Sometimes not all answers/questions are on-topic but then they can be edited if needed. No need to make a huge argument out of this. I think most people are willing to edit their posts if others think they need it.

In the end we are here to learn, share teachings, practice, develop, cultivate.

Comment: What grounds do you say this is spam? This is not being strict or not. It is being content here should reflect the Buddhist POV and should be presented in such a way.

Comment: "The only thing necessary for the triumph of evil is for **good men to do nothing.**" I am not saying Moderators have evil intention. But some one must take action, or at least protest, when something does not align with one's convictions. Emphasis on the last part of it.

Comment: The purpose of this is set a precedence on the moderators should also follow the community rules including being on topic (presented being in a Buddhist POV and / or perspective). Setting a precedence is helpful for the future and I do not think is Spam.

Comment: `No need to make a huge argument out of this.` The arguments resulted because ChrisW was not owning upto this mistake and making amends, hough later I see he has. If someone is not vocal about these matters things will just pass by with no action taken. Even if action is not taken, there at least should be a record, than being silent, as I feel. If you followed the argument, also I am the one who ended the argument when it seemed ChrisW was beyond reason and I was not getting through to him.

Comment: And if not body is vocal about something, things become the norm through practice. This is the way it always was or has been done. This is accepted as this has happening repeatedly. This is how things as always being. And as this mentality develops it reinforces itself and nobody eventually cares. To conclude the 2 points I wanted to make: 1) content should reflect it is coming from and Buddhism POV or perspective to the reader 2) stick by the standards you want other to follow. If you want other to follow something you should be stricter (at least the same) than what you try to impose.

Comment: Also if incident happens more than once and raised again. It should not be considered a duplicated. If no result of right result did not come before then there is no way to revisit it. Maybe it can be marked as a duplicate with the original posting happening in the marked posts, but based on necessity users should be raise similar issues again and again. When using past post to discuss might sometimes "muddy up" the history past record or time line should be done with caution. Also it might mean information may get lost in the clutter. So in cases post may be better.

Comment: Also if similar meta posts are not allowed this can be used as means to defend one's turf or status quo. It would be dangerous if this happens.

Comment: Also unrelated. Before asking about information others may take for grant do some research before hand.

Comment: Well I don't see any harm done. There were no unwholesome intentions involved. The answer can be edited. Let it go. No need to blow this out of proportions.

Comment: OK. Great. Let's move on. `No need to blow this out of proportions.` this happened because ChrisW did not wanted to answer which the would be readers cannot for see or does not look like coming from a Buddhist perspective / POV. I kept insisting and he was adamant to stand his ground than correct it. I had to do whatever needed make sure the avenues were exhausted, and was on record. I am not means saying about strictness (this is side tracking), though I think moderators should be stricter than the usual uses when they do something on the site. The site should be accommodating not alienating.

Comment: Basically whatever it takes to get some result. (See it through to the end.) If there is not from what you put in you have to intensify. Otherwise there no point in trying to make a point if you wear are not committed to go all the way. If a result has tuned up earlier, proportion of effort would have been less. Simplest thing would have been to make some edits to show how it link up or related to Buddhist concepts. If this had happened early the proportion and extent of effort of my engagement would have been less. It would have been a lot easier on me also if this was the case.

Comment: I'm not going to spend time arguing over such small things. A human life is too short and precious. Know that moderators and members here do their best for our community. No one is perfect, including you. That is why we practice. To cultivate and purify.

Comment: I also do not want to argue. When you cannot find a simple solution I feel you have to escalate it until you do. If someone does not do it then is also not in the communities best interest. Otherwise it will alienate uses and increase turnover losing participants. Apart from that when users see a mod does not do things by what he wants them to comply this will also cause bitterness. I feel this needs escalation, when things get solved in simple way. I am also doing the best for the community, admittingly not that successful and perfect, as yet.

Comment: Also unchecked power and authority can be dangerous.

Comment: Well that is your own opinion. It is your own Kamma. I don't think Chris have done anything wrong. His intentions were to help another being. Thats it. If the answer needs to have a Buddhist element too, then this can be added. Simple as that. No need to complicate Samsara more than it already is. As you know very well, in Buddhism intention is what matters. Everyone makes mistakes. I do, you do, everyone does. Thats why we are here trying to purify and cultivate. Its a learning process.

Comment: I think you are a great benefit to this Community. You have a lot of knowledge that you share. But you ruin some it by behaving in this way. Overreacting, blowing things out of proportions. Relax, take a breath. Lets support each other instead of causing division.

Comment: `The arguments resulted because ChrisW was not owning up to this mistake and making amends, though later I see he has` @SumindaSirinathS.Dharmasena I didn't think my answer (or the OP) would benefit from some added references to theory. But the community (in this case, both you *and* Lanka) thought I should, and so I did. I hope that addition or this discussion was helpful.

Comment: `Also if similar meta posts are not allowed` I hope we have had sufficiently many meta-topics now about what moderators do or don't do, and don't need any more. If/when we have more meta-topics I hope they'll be about the content of the site (e.g. what topics are permitted or not), and meta-topics tagged [meta-tag:specific-question] and [meta-tag:specific-answer] which discuss how to improve specific questions and answers.

Comment: It did not need references. This again is trying to divert the issue. It should be from a Buddhist POV. It should relate to Buddhist concepts. If someone newcomer reads it can they will they feel it is Buddhist or can connect the dots. The original answer no. If you had just put `You should guard your sense doors: ...` of something like this connection is made. Reference != citation. Also though part of a greater problem can arise due to a specific topic. Addressing the specific issue will not address the greater problem. If this line off reasoning is used it can be used to part suppress.

Comment: Also some times a due to a specific issue a more broader issue may pop up which might have not been properly addressed. If restricted to specific issues. The Broader can be easily swept under the carpet or suppressed, because they are not specific. If the underlying issue is not addressed, same problems will keep popping up, perhaps in different forms. The specific case may be just the surface problem only. Not the underlying issue, root issue, greater issue (when specific issue is a sub issue), related issue, connected issue, similar issue, dependent issue, etc.

Comment: `Everyone makes mistakes. I do, you do, everyone does. `. Mistakes can be made even by moderators. When these mistakes are made they should be put right swiftly than trying hold one's ground. Issue is how will prevent mistakes and now to address them swiftly when they arise, anot not level them hanging and lingering which the general users may not like, since they may had different experience in similar situation. This will lead to user turnover. Unless you attract and retain users there will be no site for the mods to moderate, at least not a thriving site.

Comment: The answer has been edited. Matter resolved. I'm closing this discussion here.

Answer (score 0):

Afaik it's not up to any user here to determine what is and isn't Buddhism or what is and isn't tied to Buddhism as is done in OP examples.

Ie a user here might post about gods & ghosts and another user will proceed to downvote his post and explain that gods are wealthy people and ghosts are loose women.

This is fine.

I think mods are generally well behaved and therefore not reported much.

Also if u think a mod is out of line a lot then there is a process to complain & remove them if found in some serious violations.

Comment: Well, we have deleted obviously off topic answers like the preaching of the Christian gospel or spam or abusive content. But anything which is broadly related to Buddhism is accepted. If the users feel the answer is wrong, they can downvote it.

Comment: My point is that unless it is specified as not-buddhism then it is good for this site. Ie would you delete an answer which claims that loose women are hungry ghosts and devas are aristocrats according to Buddhism?

Comment: Perhaps you would otherwise delete an opposing answer which claims that hungry ghosts are a class of beings and that it is an unfortunate destination that beings go to after passing away from ie a human existence.

Comment: I know you [moderators] wouldn't delete any of it and both of these answers can't Buddhism as it was supposed to be taught.

Comment: Therefore my point is that moderators are here just to keep it civil and delete spam. Moderators aren't even supposed to delete Christian gospel preaching unless it is specified explicitly as non-Buddhism, it's not about the arbitration of truth or measuring one's Buddhism and that's fine.

Comment: I am not interested in beating a dead horse here. My whole point was that the OPs examples weren't good examples of misconduct in light of the efective policies.

Answer (score 0):

All the moderators here are celestial Buddhas, so obviously hypocrisy and rules of behaviour etc. don't apply to them.

Sorry, that was the snarky answer. If anything, moderators should be fairer, more even handed, and politer, than anyone.